# How to check whether the cursor is at the boundary of a syntax item for indentexpr?

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting, indentation

I'm writing my own `indentexpr` to indent my code, the `indentexpr` is run in a sandbox, so one important point is that I cannot change the text content.

I have set up the syntax highlighting for quoted strings, how do I know the cursor is at the boundary `"` in this case?

```js
"A""B"
  ^^
```

Two strings `"A"` and `"B"` stick together. The API `synIDattr()` can let me know the name of the syntax item, say "myString", but cannot tell the start and end of this item.

I cannot simply move the cursor from `"A"` to `"B"` (or vise versa) and say I find the last quote of `"A"`.

Is there an easy way to tell the difference between `"A"` and `"B"` without manually counting quotes (for performance)?

---

The example above is made up for easier comprehension. The real use case is about multiline strings. For example:

```python
var s = "A
"
"B".shout()

s = """A
"""
"B".shout()
```

Comment: You could do a "search for boundaries" function that check the id under the cursor and move left-right until this id change, this will give you the boundaries.

Comment: @Nobe4 `synID()` gives the same id for both `"A"` and `"B"`.

Comment: because they are both strings? It's normal. I'm not sure I understand your question here...

Comment: @Nobe4 Edited. Two strings stick together, so there is no non-string characters in the middle of them to tell the boundary.

Comment: I understand the problem, but I don't understand the need.  `indentexpr` would affect the space before `"A"`, not between `"A"` and `"B"`.  If `""` is meant to be a quote escape, that would mean that `"A""B"` is a whole string.  If they are actually supposed to be two separate strings, I would consider that a syntax error and not bother.

Comment: @TommyA Sorry. I've added back the real code. Two strings can be on different lines. And they can span multiple lines.

Comment: @V.D.D I answered the issue regarding string boundaries, but in the case of `indentexpr`, wouldn't the parent block affect the indentation regardless?

Comment: @TommyA Because I need to know the previous string is indeed closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem I encountered in my plugin: [braceless.vim](https://github.com/tweekmonster/braceless.vim).  You won't be able to do this using only syntax groups.  Some syntaxes make a distinction between strings and heredoc/docstring, but you will still face the same problem if those are sitting next to each other.  Here is the relevant snippet from braceless.vim:

```
let s:docstr = '\%("""\|''''''\)'
let s:syn_string = '\%(String\|Heredoc\|DoctestValue\|DocTest\|DocTest2\|BytesEscape\)$'


" Test if the line is a string.  Accepts a column number to test.  If no 
" column number is provided, test the first and last column of the line.
function! s:is_string(line, ...)
  return synIDattr(synID(a:line, a:0 ? a:1 : col([a:line, '$']) - 1, 1), 'name') =~? s:syn_string
        \ && (a:0 || synIDattr(synID(a:line, 1, 1), 'name') =~? s:syn_string)
endfunction


" Returns the start and end lines for docstrings.  Accepts a second argument
" to limit the search.
function! s:docstring(line, ...)
  let l = nextnonblank(a:line)
  let doc_head = 0
  let doc_tail = 0

  let bounds = a:0 ? a:1 : [1, line('$')]

  while l >= bounds[0]
    if getline(l) =~ s:docstr && s:is_string(nextnonblank(l + 1))
          \ && !s:is_string(prevnonblank(l - 1))
      let doc_head = l
      break
    elseif !s:is_string(l)
      break
    endif
    let l = prevnonblank(l - 1)
  endwhile

  if doc_head == 0
    return [0, 0]
  endif

  let l = prevnonblank(a:line)
  while l <= bounds[1]
    if getline(l) =~ s:docstr && s:is_string(prevnonblank(l - 1))
          \ && !s:is_string(nextnonblank(l + 1))
      let doc_tail = l
      break
    elseif !s:is_string(l)
      break
    endif
    let l = nextnonblank(l + 1)
  endwhile

  return [doc_head, doc_tail]
endfunction
```

`s:docstring()` starts by searching backwards from the supplied line number.  If it finds a matching docstring delimiter on the current line, it tests the previous line to see if it's not a string that spans an entire line.  This makes up for cases where a double quoted docstring might have single quote docstring delimiters in it (`"""a\n'''\nb"""`).  It otherwise stops searching on the first non-blank non-string line encountered.  If it finds the beginning delimiter, it continues the search in the opposite direction from the supplied line number.  The speed of this function depends on how large the docstring block is.

In this case:

```
s = """A
"""
"B".shout()
```

`s:docstring()` could determine that `"B"` is not part of the docstring above it.  But, for:

```
var s = "A
"
"B".shout()
```

You would have to adapt the function to search for standard string delimiters, and search for standard string boundaries *after* you have determined that the current line is not in a docstring.

For my plugin's needs, I considered contiguous docstrings to be an entire block since they would indent to the same level.  If you still want to make a distinction between:

```
"""
A
"""
"""
B
"""
```

You could change the following line:

```
if getline(l) =~ s:docstr && s:is_string(nextnonblank(l + 1))
      \ && (!s:is_string(prevnonblank(l - 1)) || getline(prevnonblank(l - 1)) !~ s:docstr)
```

That way, if the previous non-blank line is not a string *or* another docstring delimiter is encountered, it would take the current line as the beginning of the docstring. But, this would break the case cited above for mixed docstring delimiters (`"""a\n'''\nb"""`).

For the sake of speed in `indentexpr`, the function could be modified to *only* search backwards, since indentation depends the lines above the current line.

Comment: Ah, I have to count the quote with regexps. Thanks!